# Need help understanding what a RegEx does, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
///^index\s([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\.\.([0-9A-Fa-f]+)\s?(.+)?$///
```

As far as I can tell, it searches for the word `index` at the start.. then I'm lost..

Comment: May I suggest the [MDN entry for Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line by line:

```
^    //start of the line
index    //the literal string 'index'
\s //a whitespace char
([0-9A-Fa-f]+) //1 or more characters from the given set
\.\. //two literal periods
([0-9A-Fa-f]+) //1 or more characters from given set
\s? //0 or 1 whitespace characters
(.+)? //0 or 1 multiples of 1 or more periods
$ //end of the line
```

So...looks like it's matching Hexadecimal encoded strings with some weird formatting:

```
index 9A9A..ACAC..........
```

should match.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/fF7zO9) to explain that:

[image]

Comment: @maerics - I posted a link right there in the answer...

Comment: awesome, didn't know about that website

Comment: That site is brilliant. Bookmarked.

Answer (score 2):

I use regexper for these kinds of things: http://www.regexper.com/

[image]

It just fits my brain better to see a graphical flow diagram.

From this I can tell it's looking for lines such as:

`index 9F..A0 something`

And capturing both hexadecimal numbers and the final something as substring matches.